# WP7: Push Notification Subscription Lifetime?

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, lifetime, mpns

When a subscription has been created by a client/phone on the MPN-server, for how long is it alive? When will it become closed? Do my app-users have to start my app and create a new channel every now and then to keep a connection open?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no guaranteed lifetime.
The recommendation is to check the subscription every time the application starts and update your remote details as necessary.

**Update:**
[Apparently](http://www.learningwindowsphone.com/blog/?p=93), the channel should be good until there's 30 days of inactivity or an invalid payload.
In practice, always check when your app starts. :)

Comment: I see, but what could a approx lifetime be, 5 min? 1 hour? A day?

Comment: @Andreas Expect days rather than minutes but ALWYAS check for changes when your app starts or at other relevant points in your application.